# How to embed images in MIME mail system?

Tags: emails

How to progamatically embed images in mail?
I am using mime and mail system module

Here is my code:

```
function send_rush_me_mail($node){
  $dataArr = array();
  $dataArr['field_name'] = $node->field_name['und'][0]['value'];
  $dataArr['field_email'] = $node->field_email['und'][0]['value'];
  $body = location_beacon_email_body_string('rush_me', $dataArr);
  $params = array(
    'body' => $body,
    'subject' => 'Auto Response for Ask Me',
  );

  drupal_mail('register', 'register', $dataArr['field_email'], language_default(), $params, 'example@domain.com', TRUE);
  watchdog('Ask me mail', print_r($params,1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and filtered HTML text format allowing **img** tag in the format you could send HTML emails with images.

Here is a summary of the required steps:

1. Enable the required modules, eg using Drush like so: `drush dl rules entity mimemail mailsystem`
2. Configure the **MAIL SYSTEM SETTINGS** choosing **MimeMailSystem** the **Site-wide default** and **Mime Mail module class** from `admin/config/system/mailsystem`
3. Set the text format to be filtered html or the format that allows img tag from `admin/config/system/mimemail`
4. Use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to send html e-mails.

For a more detailed tutorial, refer to [How to Send HTML Emails in Drupal 7 using Rules](https://www.webwash.net/how-to-send-html-emails-in-drupal-7-using-rules/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want to do it programatically

Comment: Implement the hook_mail and set the text format to append the img tag

Comment: First the code is not readable at all, add it the question body, Do up votes to attract attention to your question

Answer (score 0):

you need to install 2 modules to make your email working and in mime mail config set the E-mail format to full html to send images

Mail System

[mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem)

Mime Mail

[mime](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail)

you can use the example module from drupal offical

[example](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples)

in this u will find example_email module and in that module u will get all the source code and check the below link for the explanation on each function
[EmailExample](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/email_example%21email_example.module/7)

This will help you, send emails pragmatically i have used the same and i am able to sent the email.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically

Comment: the 2 modules are basic requirement to send email programatically, if you have checked the 

https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/email_example%21email_example.module/7 

you will get the functions to be used for sending email and with the help of this u can send emails programatically as well the example module code